# Как исправить ошибку: "warning C6385: Переполнение буфера при записи в ... "?

Tags: c++, c, warning, realloc, calloc

// Массив должен выводится с доп. столбцом в начале  и после этого выдавать запрос на продолжение работы в программе или выход. Переполнение происходит после вывода массива с доп столбцом.

Main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Functions.h"


int main(void)
{
    int n, m, i;
    int **a;
    char s = 'n';
    while (s != 'Y' && s != 'y')
    {
        printf("\n Enter the dimension of the matrix A[n][m]");
        printf("\n Number of columns N = ");
        scanf_s(" %d", &n);
        printf("\n Number of rows M = ");
        scanf_s(" %d", &m);
        if ((a = (int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*))) == 0)
        {
            printf("\n Memory allocation failure Array **a \n");
            exit(1);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if ((a[i] = (int*)calloc(m, sizeof(int))) == 0)
            {
                printf("\n Memory allocation failure Array *a \n");
                exit(1);
            }
        ReadMatr(a, n, m);
        PrintMatr(a, n, m);
        AddColumn(a, n, m);
        freeArray(a, n);

    printf("Close program \n Y - Yes N - No \n");
    s = _getch();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Functions.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "functions.h"


void ReadMatr(int **M, int n, int m)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j<m; j++)
            M[i][j] = rand() % (n*m);
    return;
}

void PrintMatr(int **M, int n, int m)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("\n Output matrix A[%d][%d]:\n", n, m);
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<m; j++)
            printf(" %4d ", M[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}

void AddColumn(int **M, int n, int m)
{
    int i, j, *Temp;
    int C1 = m + 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((Temp = (int*)realloc(M[i], C1 * sizeof(int))) == 0)
        {
            printf("Memory allocation failure after expanding for *a");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = m; i < C1; i++) {
        if ((M[i] = (int *)calloc(n, sizeof(int))) == 0) {
            printf("\nMemory allocation failure *a");
            exit(1);
        }

            for (j = m; j < C1; j++)
                M[i][j] = rand() % (n*m);
        printf("\n Output matrix with an additional column A[%d][%d]:\n", n, m);

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (j = C1; j > 0; j--)
            {
                 int Temp = M[i][j - 1];
                M[i][j] = M[i][j - 1];
                M[i][j] = Temp;

            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < C1; j++)
                printf(" %4d ", M[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return;
}

void freeArray(int **M, int n)
    {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            free(M[i]);
        }
    free(M);
    }
```

Functions.h

```
void ReadMatr(int **, int, int);
void PrintMatr(int **, int, int);
void AddColumn(int **, int, int);
void freeArray(int **, int);
```

Не могу понять как исправить эти ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что вы вообще хотите сделать в `AddColumn` ? Вы сначала для каждой строки выделяете память под ещё один элемент (`realloc`).Отлично, теперь у вас есть плюс один столбец. Потом вы заново создаёте строку (M[m]), причём не факт что такая строка вообще есть. Потом вы в этой вновь созданной строке заполняете один - последний элемент случайным значением. Дальше у вас в цикле идёт swap, который на самом деле не swap  да ещё и индекс `j` не валидный (начинается с `C1`, а должен с `C1-1`. А потом пожалуй единственное место без вопросов - вывод массива

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий! Изменял уже много всего, знаю, что нужно С1 - 1 вводить. Тогда остаётся только одна ошибка (65), но матрица почему-то меняет ВСЕ значения рандомно, а не только последнего столбца.Что я хочу сделать так это добавить столбец в начало матрицы. А как сделать правильный swap?

Comment: а чем С++ вам не нравится?..

Comment: @AlexPriest я вас понял, перепишу как я это вижу, чуть позже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корректная функция `AddColumn`:

```
void AddColumn(int **M, int n, int m)
{
    int i, j;
    int C1 = m + 1;
    //выделяем память под ещё один столбец
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((M[i] = (int*)realloc(M[i], C1 * sizeof(int))) == 0)
        {
            printf("Memory allocation failure after expanding for *a");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    //двигаем все столбцы на один вправо
    for (int j = C1-1; j > 0; j--){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            int tmp = M[i][j];
            M[i][j] = M[i][j-1];
            M[i][j-1] = tmp;
        }
    }
    //заполняем крайний слева столбец случайными числами
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        M[i][0] = rand() % (n*m);
    }
    printf("\n Output matrix with an additional column A[%d][%d]:\n", n, m);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < C1; j++)
            printf(" %4d ", M[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}
```